# Cannot install node-pty-prebuilt - too many errors

Tags: npm-install, permission-denied, android-app-signing, node-pty

I'm trying to run `expo opt-in-google-play-signing` but it throws an error after I paste the encryption key of:

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
11 warnings and 20 errors generated.
```

and

```
Run npm -g install node-pty-prebuilt to install node pty
Error: Package node-pty-prebuilt is required to use PEPK tool
```

Initially when I ran the suggested npm install I had a permission issue which was solved using `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules` but then when I run the solution `npm -g install node-pty-prebuilt` it fails again on:

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
11 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--build_v8_with_gn=false"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-pty-prebuilt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install script.
```

If run with sudo I get:

```
prebuild-install WARN install EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/uxdw/.npm'
```

Running the chown script doesn't seem to solve the above access this time, giving:

```
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/uxdw/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.16.2"
```

This is being run as the admin account on a macbook on Mojave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by simply downgrading the active Node version.
At the time of writing it worked fine with either v10.12.0 or v10.13.0.

I used Node Version Manager (NVM) to hot-swap between versions.

Install NVM:

```
Brew install nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh (relinks nvm until is set as default on Terminal launch)
```

Install Node versions:

```
nvm install node // install node
nvm install 8.9  // install specific version
nvm uninstall x.x // uninstall specific version
```

swap to a specific version:

```
nvm use x.x // use a specific version
```

For further details: [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)